# getting input from stdin

Tags: java, io, stdin

I want to get input from stdin in the for of

```
3
10 20 30
```

the first number is the amount of numbers in the second line. Here's what I got, but it is stuck in the while loop... so I believe. I ran in debug mode and the array is not getting assign any values...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tester {   

   public static void main (String[] args)
   {

       int testNum;
       int[] testCases;

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Enter test number");
       testNum = in.nextInt();

       testCases = new int[testNum];

       int i = 0;

       while(in.hasNextInt()) {
           testCases[i] = in.nextInt();
           i++;
       }

       for(Integer t : testCases) {
           if(t != null)
               System.out.println(t.toString());               
       }

   } 

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It has to do with the condition.

```
in.hasNextInt()
```

It lets you keep looping and then after three iterations 'i' value equals to 4 and testCases[4] throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

The Solution to do this could be

```
for (int i = 0; i < testNum; i++) {
 *//do something*
}
```

Comment: thanks.. for some reason it works with the for loop; however it doesn't work with the while loop.. even after adding the condition

Answer (score 2):

Update your while to read only desired numbers as below:

```
      while(i < testNum && in.hasNextInt()) {
```

The additional condition `&& i < testNum` added in `while` will stop reading the numbers once your have read the numbers equivalent to your array size, otherwise it will go indefininte and you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` when number array `testCases` is full i.e. you are done reading with `testNum` numbers.

Comment: why it works with the for loop, but I tried your method and it didn't work, the strange thing is that it should as I'm updating the 'i' variable with each iteration

Comment: there's something with hasNextInt() method that keeps looping or waiting for next int...

Comment: @miatech  It was silly. We need to put `i < testNum` as first condition and `in.hasNextInt()` as second. I updated the answer and it works perfectly. Earlier `in.hasNextInt()` was waiting for one more input before going to evaluate the condition. Please try and let me know.